# Magento change base image without images in import folder

Tags: php, magento

We have had a little problem with our images which is that all the products don't have base image. So we want to change this without using the import folder with all the images in it, cause it'll take a very long time to upload all the images to the import folder.
My question is if that is possible to do?
I have already tried this code:

```
<?php
  $product_id = 3766;
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
    if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
    if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
    $product->save();
}
?>
```

This gives no error but does nothing for us.

Yet, we have also used this code:

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
    if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
    if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
    $product->save();
}
```

But this one gives us this error:
Fatal error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 53 bytes) in home*********.netlibVarienObject.php on line 270
Any suggestions? Any incorrect things in the code?